# Integration of Keycloak event listener with SprinBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, keycloak, spring-kafka, event-driven-design

I wrote my custom Event listener SPI plugin that console logs all events (user event + admin event) in Keycloak. I deployed it in my Keycloak server and tested; everything works fine.

Now, what could be the best way to send events from my plugin to my Springboot application?

Webhooks or REST api is an option but it's quite difficult to work with for larger application and introduces extra hassle of syncing when services are offline. Something like Kafka might be better for this use case, but I am not sure. I want to know if there are other better options available for this use case?
Edit

Comment: Hello! Sorry I'm marking this question as off-topic, since stackoverflow is not the place to find library - tool recommendations. Kafka might be a choice, but it really depends on your use case.

Comment: Ready to use extension: https://www.keycloak.org/extensions.html